# How to use makefile file on windows?

Tags: makefile

I need to use a package from Github on windows. The package's website is: https://github.com/atpaajan/fds2fem. This package is a command-line tool and the only way to use it is to type the command "fds2fem targetfile" in terminal. However, in the src folder where the source code locates, there is no such executable program named fds2fem. I noticed that there is a makefile in the src folder, together with a bunch of .f90 files. I guess we need to compile these codes to generate a fds2fem executable? Does anyone know how to compile this?

---

My try: I have installed Choco to install make on Windows 11. Then I use the following command on the makefile to compile the code,

```
> make makefile 
make: Nothing to be done for 'makefile'.
```

and there was nothing changed in the folder. Do I use the correct command? Any thoughts? Thanks!

---

The following is the content of makefile.

```
# Makefile

INST_DIR=$(HOME)/bin

# Compilation instructions

FC= ifort
FFLAGS= -free -O3 -traceback
LDFLAGS=
OBJ= global.o string.o error.o misc.o math.o cfg_reader.o fds_dump.o fds_reader.o cfast_dump.o iso_reader.o \
         fds_stats.o fem_dump.o fem_stats.o abaqus_reader.o abaqus_output.o \
         ansys_reader.o ansys_output.o matching.o \
         mapping.o mapping_iso.o main.o 

fds2fem_db : FFLAGS= -free -m64 -check -warn all -O0 -auto -WB -traceback -g -fpe0 -fltconsistency -no-wrap-margin

fds2fem: $(OBJ)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o fds2fem $(OBJ)

fds2fem_db: $(OBJ)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o fds2fem_db $(OBJ)

%.o: %.f90
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $<

install:
    cp fds2fem $(INST_DIR)

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.mod
```

---

2nd try. This time I use just `make` in cmd and now I met a new error.

```
> make
ifort -free -O3 -traceback -c global.f90
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, ifort -free -O3 -traceback -c global.f90, ...) failed.
make (e=2):
makefile:24: recipe for target 'global.o' failed
make: *** [global.o] Error 2
```

I also tried mingw32-make but it remains the same. Any thoughts on this error? Thanks!

---

3rd try: current progress: thanks for the comment from @datenwolf, I realized that system cannot recognize 'ifort', so I added 'ifort.exe' in the visual studio 2019 package into the path and now it works. A lot of new .obj files have been generated. However, a new error emerges as follows,

```
ifort: command line warning #10161: unrecognized source type 'global.o'; object file assumed
ipo: error #11018: Cannot open global.o
```

I noticed that those new files are of type '.obj' instead of '.o'. Could this be the reason for this error? Any thoughts? Thx.

Comment: `make makefile` tells `make` to rebuild the target `makefile` -- not what you want.  Try just `make` on its own, or `make -f makefile` .

Comment: @G.M. Thx for commenting. I followed your advice. Now I met a new problem. The error has been updated in the post. Any advice? Thx again.

Comment: @JonasLionel did you install a Fortran compiler?

Comment: @datenwolf I have installed visual studio 2019 and it contains a Fortran compiler.

Comment: @JonasLionel well, the problem is, that whatever why you installed make, it probably doesn't know about that and where Visual Studio is available on your system. In addition to that, the Fortran Compiler that comes with VS probably isn't named `ifort`. I think your best course of action would be to install `msys2`, then therein install gnufortran and make and build with that.

Comment: @datenwolf Thx for your advice. Plz see the new update on my 3rd try. Thx!

Comment: An update: I found that the makefile is written in Linux syntax. Therefore it works only in a Linux environment and it does.